# How run to VSCode tasks in JavaScript Debug Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want VSCode to run this task:

```
{
  "label": "Start",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "npm run start",
  "dependsOn": ["Set Envs"],
  "problemMatcher": [],
  "presentation": {
  "group": "Main",
  "reveal": "always",
  "close": false
}
```

In a JavaScript Debug Terminal. Is there a way to do that?