# Run javascript debug terminal with tasks

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70769860/how-run-to-vscode-tasks-in-javascript-debug-terminal) but no answer.

How can we run a JavaScript Debug Terminal instead of a classic shell for `tasks.json` ?

I actually use it to run several npm goals at startup, but for some of them I need some debugging. I have to stop process, open terminal and then restart my app in this dedicated terminal.

One of my actual `tasks.json` task :

```
{
    "label": "webpack",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "npm run -s start-webpack -- -w",
    "isBackground": false,
    "problemMatcher": [],
    "presentation": {
        "group": "main"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using a different approach to debug NodeJS applications: [Auto Attach](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach) instead of JavaScript Debug Terminal.

After creating a Task and setting `"task.allowAutomaticTasks": "on"`, press `Ctrl + Shift + P` to open the command palette, search for `Debug: Toggle Auto Attach`, set it to Smart, restart vscode and it just works.

This is the created Task for reference:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "start:dev",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "npm: start:dev",
            "detail": "nodemon",
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```